# Transparent background in editor but solid text

Tags: linux, ubuntu, transparency

Is there a way to make the background to an editor e.g. gedit transparent without affecting text's transparency? Is there any other program that supports this?

Comment: @akira Then I guess those who thought making terminal transparent are idiots according to you? I'm sure  What I'm asking is that transparency but with the text solid to be more readable and all that in a text editor.

Comment: @user64886: correct, it is just bad contrast and it irritates the eye, no matter how clear the text is.

Comment: This is most likely entirely dependent on the software you're using. I don't think there's a generally applicable solution.

Answer (score 2):

It is kind of easy to do if you use a command line editor like `vim` inside a `gnome-terminal`. Go to "Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Background" and select a transparent background.

Comment: I think he's looking for a general-purpose solution, something that could affect all GTK text-area's, etc.